# Am I able to use table.concat as a set of arguments?

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm using LOVE2D to get used to lua a bit more, and I am trying to call a function to make a circle appear on screen, there's 5 arguments, and I have a table known as 'button' with the required arguments in it. I want to use table.concat to to fill in all the blank arguments but it won't let me. Is there anyway to do this?

```
function toRGB(r,g,b)
    return r/255,g/255,b/255
end

function love.load()
    button = {}
    button.mode = "fill"
    button.x = 0
    button.y = 0
    button.size = 30
end

function love.draw()
    love.graphics.setColor(toRGB(60,60,60))
    love.graphics.circle(table.concat(button))
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`table.concat` returns a string. That's not what you want.

To get a list of table elements use `table.unpack`. But this function does only work with tables that have consecutive numeric indices starting from 1.

Also `love.graphics.circle` accesses its parameters by position, not by name. Hence you have to ensure that the expression list you put into that function has the right order.

So something like:

```
button = {"fill", 0, 0, 30}
love.graphics.circle(table.unpack(button))
```

would work.

If you're using other table keys as in your example you'll have to write a function that returns the values in the right order.

In the simplest case

```
button = {}
button.mode = "fill"
button.x = 0
button.y = 0
button.size = 30
button.unpack = function() return button.mode, button.x, button.y, button.size end
love.graphics.circle(button.unpack())
```

Or you can do something like this:

```
function drawCircle(params)
  love.graphics.circle(params.mode, params.x, params.y, params.size)
end
drawCircle(button)
```

There are many other ways to achieve this.